# Pagination resets checkbox of rows

Tags: grails, checkbox, groovy, html-table, gsp

I have a GSP containing some rows with an checkbox which lets the user select several rows.

```
 <table>
<thead>
    <tr>
    // Column headers
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <g:each in="${itemList}" status="i"
                var="instance">
        <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
            // Some other rows
            <td>
                <g:checkBox name="selected"
                                value="${instance.id}"
                                checked="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </g:each>
</tbody>
```

And a pagination under my table:

```
    <div class="pagination">
        <g:paginate total="${total}" params="${params}"/>
    </div>
```

Now the problem is when I switch from Page 1 -> Page 2 -> and then back to Page 1 all the checkboxes from Page 1 are reseted.

As pagination calls the list controller method I checked the following on page switch by Watching the following in Debugger when list controller method gets called:

```
params.list('selected')
```

But unfortunately the list is empty.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your table in a `<form></form>` then checking the params?

Answer (score 0):

Pagination does not submit a form (or at least not like you're thinking it does; I really don't remember if the underlying logic uses a form or not) so your checkboxes are not being submitted to anywhere.

You need to consider different approaches for having your form submitted so that your checkbox selections are persisted.  Two approaches could be:

1. Write your own pagination tag that wraps g.paginate and modifies which params are sent so that your checkbox values are included.
2. Add ajax handling to your checkboxes so that they are submitted immediately when changed.